# Push notifications using ConnectyCube on React Native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, connectycube

I'm trying to using push notifications using ConnectyCube on React Native. Main problem is that if I send a notification from the admin panel of ConnectyCube (or from source code), the admin panel says that the notification has been successfully delivered, but nothing happens on the android emulator. Maybe someone can think that there are some bugs client-side in the implementation of my onMessageListener:

```
notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
    console.log("Hi!")
});
```

Anyway, if I try to send a notification through the Firebase console, all works and I receive the notification. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a wrong method: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/introduction

The React Native Firebase Notifications Module deals with notification-only and notification + data FCM remote messages.

For data-only FCM messages please see the Messaging module.

ConnectyCube sends a data push messages. 
Therefore, please try using Messaging module according to this guide: 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I was using a wrong method!

Comment: how can i get notification + data push messages from ConnectyCube?

Comment: All the notifications are 'data' notification. So you can process them as you wish and then show a notification with any text, so this is more universal

Comment: I cant access data when app is in background in IOS (react native).Its only show message but i have pass object of message on connectycube payload i want show sender name also. how can i achieve that in react native IOS?

Comment: A sender name can be a part of push notification body, so you do not need to configure it. Please go to ConnectyCube dashboard, Chat module, Offline Notifications. Here you can configure a push template